# Error while running the MongoDB as a Statefulset set in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to run the `mongodb` as a `statefulset` in the `minikube` Kubernetes cluster. I have 3 replicas but I have the following problem - which is, one replica (mongo-0) is up and running without any issue  but the second replica (mongo-1) is forever in the `pending` state. I tried to describe the pod and I get the following output:

```
kubectl describe pod mongo-1 -n ng-mongo

. . .

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  17m (x70 over 6h9m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

As per the above error, it says it cannot find the persistent volume, but there is one already.

Please find my YAML definitions for this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
  namespace: ng-mongo
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-pv
  namespace: ng-mongo
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /tmp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - minikube 
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-claim
  namespace: ng-mongo
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
---
apiVersion: v1   
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: ng-mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1    
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: ng-mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"            
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: 200Mi            
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: localvolume
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
      # volumes:
      #   - name: localvolume
      #     persistentVolumeClaim:
      #       claimName: local-claim

  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: localvolume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "local-storage"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

Can someone help me find the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the node affinity while creating the PV, that need to be configured correctly:

It will  inform Kubernetes my disk will attach to this type of node. Due to affinity your PV is attached to one type of specific node only.

when you are deploying the deployment it's not getting scheduled on that specific node and your POD is not getting that PV or PVC.

If you are adding node affinity to PVC add it to deployment also. So both PVC and pod get scheduled on the same node.

**Resolution steps:**

Make sure both deployment and pvc schedule with the same node add the node affinity to deployment also so deployment  schedule on the respective node.

or else

Remove the node affinity rule from PV and create a new PV and PVC and use it.
here is the place where you have mentioned the node affinity rule

**Note:** In your node affinity you have mentioned as minikube, verify the node by
`kubectl get nodes` make changes if required.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am using `minikube` and with only 1 node. In that case, how this is applicable?

Comment: Add the node infinity in pvc also and mention the node name.